# Getting selected elements with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-select2

I'm using select2 to create a selectable list, and a button to print out the selected items like this:

```
<select ng-model = "selectedRatios" ng-options = "ratio.name for ratio in ratios" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple = "multiple">

</select>

<button ng-click="printSelected();">Print ratios</button>
```

my `printSelected` function looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('IndexApp', []);

app.controller('IndexController',['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

  $http.get('/ratios').success(function(result) {

    console.log(result);
    $scope.ratios = result;


  });

  $scope.printSelected = function() {
    console.log($scope.selectedRatios);
  }


}]);
```

The problem is that the `printSelected` function always prints out `undefined` and I can't figure out why. Is it wrong to assume you'll get the selected elements directly from the `ng-model` of the selectable list?

**EDIT:**

When I remove the jQuery script code for using select2, the printSelected function works as expected, but the list obviously does no longer look or work as wanted.

What I removed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();



</script>
```

Comment: I think your code seems to be correct. Could you setup jsfiddle or something? [My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/zp82e3xm/1/) seems to work fine.

Comment: @yazaki It seems to be the jQuery script that causes the problem, when I remove it the printButton works as expected. See above.